# Optimizing ng-repeat digest loop for iPad devices

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a bootstrap 3 modal in my angularjs app. I have a standard ng-repeat with about 30 rows:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div ng-repeat="table in tables track by table.Id">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-style="tableStyle(table)" ng-  
       class="tableClass(table)"
    ng-click="setTable(table)"  bo-text="table.name">
    </button>
</div>
```

When the modal loads, the first digest loop takes about 300ms the first time around to load. 3 more digest loops are called that only take 20ms each. Commenting out the ng-repeat it's super quick and takes 100ms less. Every ng-repeat I add increases the first digest time by about 100ms.

Can someone explain how digest works with ng-repeat? And why the subsequent digest loops are so much quicker?